# jquery: detect when one of the elements of each function is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, alert, each

I'm doing in my js file:

```
var aryYears= [];
    $(".year").each(function(){
        aryYears.push($(this).val());
    })
```

So I can send an array of years as a parameter in the saveChanges function.

I need the field year to be required. 
How can I check in the code above if each of the years of the array has a value? 
How can I fire an alert or a dialog in case the year is empty?

Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Have you considered `if ($(this).val() === "") { ...`? You may also like to include [some kind of trim function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) in case the user tries to get around the validation by entering a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this to check if array is empty or not

```
 $(".year").each(function(){
   var val =  $(this).val();
   if(val)
     aryYears.push($(this).val());
   else
     alert('null/ empty');
})
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G553m/2/)

Comment: after the alert, how can I add a flag so I can do a return false; in the saveChanges function ???

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
var aryYears= [];
    $(".year").each(function(){
        var v = $(this).val();
        aryYears.push(v !== '' ? v : prompt('Please enter a year:'));
    })
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/G553m/);

Updated (after a while, due to a couple of accidental infinite loops, sigh...):

```
function getValue(v, hint) {
    if (v && v !== '') {
        return v;
    } else {
        v = prompt('Please enter a ' + hint + ': ');
        return getValue(v);
    }
}

var aryYears = [];
$(".year").each(function () {
    var v = $(this).val();
    aryYears.push(getValue(v, 'year'));
})
console.log(aryYears);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sRUKW/).

The latter sample should, if nothing else, put the user in a position where s/he gets frustrated enough to enter a value, however there's no sanity-checking of that value; so please do remember to validate the user-input.

And a slightly more useful version, that highlights the `input` for which you're asking for a value, and also adds the value *to* that `input`:

```
function getValue(v, hint) {
    if (v && v.trim() !== '') {
        return v;
    } else {
        v = prompt('Please enter a ' + hint + ': ');
        return getValue(v, hint);
    }
}

var aryYears = [];
$(".year").each(function () {
    var self = $(this),
        v = $(this).val();
    if (!v || v === '') {
        self.addClass('invalid');
    }
    v = getValue(v, 'year');
    aryYears.push(v);
    self.removeClass('invalid').val(v);
})
console.log(aryYears);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sRUKW/2/).

Comment: `prompt()?` What if the user closes the prompt without entering a value?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
var aryYears= [];
$(".year").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "") {
        alert("The value of .year is empty");
    } else {
        aryYears.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var aryYears = $(".year").map(function(){
        if(this.value !== "")
         return this.value;
    }).get();

if(aryYears.length < $('.year').length){
  alert("please enter all values");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
$('.something').each(function() {
    var checkValue = $(this).val();
    checkValue = $.trim(checkValue);
    if (Math.floor(checkValue) == checkValue && $.isNumeric(checkValue)) {
       if (checkValue == "") {
            alert('not value'); 
      }
    }
});
```